# Illogical result using Order By along with Partition By

Tags: sql

Let's say there is a table dd:

| id (integer) | name (varchar) | ts (date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | 2021-03-25 |
| 2 | first | 2021-03-30 |

When I query this table with following:

```
SELECT *, MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ts) max_ts FROM dd;
```

Then the result is:

| id (integer) | name (varchar) | ts (date) | max_ts (date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | 2021-03-25 | 2021-03-25 |
| 2 | first | 2021-03-30 | 2021-03-30 |

When I add "DESC" to Order By clause:

```
SELECT *, MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ts DESC) max_ts FROM dd;
```

The result is:

| id (integer) | name (varchar) | ts (date) | max_ts (date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | first | 2021-03-30 | 2021-03-30 |
| 1 | first | 2021-03-25 | 2021-03-30 |

This time the result is what I expect. Considering that I am partitioning records by name and then getting the max date from them, I expect the **max_ts** values to be the same (the max one) in both cases, since the order should not really matter when getting the max value from the group. But in fact, in the first case the result contains different **max_ts** values, not the maximum one.

Why does it work this way? Why does ordering affect the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax:

```
MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ts)
```

is a cumulative maximum ordered by `ts`.  The window frame starts with the smallest value of `ts`.  Each subsequent row is larger -- because the `ORDER BY` is the same column as `ts`.
This is not interesting; `ts` on each row *is* the cumulative maximum when ordered by `ts`.

On the other hand:

```
MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ts DESC)
```

This is the cumulative maximum in reverse order.  So, the first row in the window frame is the maximum `ts`.  All subsequent rows will be the maximum.

This is not the most efficient way to express this, though.  I think this better captures the logic you want:

```
MAX(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
```

Comment: Why does absence of "order by" clause help to solve the problem? Wouldn't the DBMS use some kind of "internal" ordering then, considering that partitions are represented by unordered sets? Moreover, some DBMS (like Oracle one) prohibit omitting "order by" clause when using "partition by".

Comment: @zuffbq . . . I would suggest that you review the documentation on window functions.  The key concept is the window frame.  With `order by` it is the range of values that match the `partition by` and are up to the value in the current row based on the `order by`.  Without `order by`, it is all values that match the `partition by` clause.  The two concepts are exactly the same.  It is just a question of the "last" row in the window frame.